# How large is the usable area in iPad Safari

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

I'm developing a web app for the iPad, to run in Safari. I don't yet have an iPad to test on. Does anyone know the usable screen size - after any space for the safari/ipad controls is takes up?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should just follow [TN2262](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html) and write dimension-invariant code.

In case you need a logical pixel size, `document.body.client[Width|Height]` is always 980×1208.

---

In terms of absolute pixels you can use, the navigation bar of Mobile Safari takes up roughly 78px, so in portrait orientation it is 768×946, and in landscape it is 1024×690.

There can be a keyboard (308px in height in portrait, 397px in landscape) as well.

**Update:** The above absolute numbers are correct only for iOS 4.x or before. In iOS 5.x Apple introduced the tab bar which increases the height of navigation bar + status bar to 96px. Actually, even before iOS 5.x, the presence of the bookmark bar can affect the viewport as well.

Comment: this is wrong, as far as I can see the measurements are actually: landscape: 1024x672 and portrait: 768x928. I think KennyTM hasn't factored in the ipad status bar at the top of the screen..

Comment: @user333216: It was not wrong. Please consider that in 2010 the Safari doesn't have a tab bar. For example in http://www.ipatrix.com/wp-content/uploads/17-Safari.png the navigation bar + status bar *is* 78px high. See updated answer.

Comment: No such thing as "dimension-invariant code". The idea behind responsive design is "make the best of every device", and knowing most common resolutions on real devices helps to get it right. That's why I feel this question is important

Comment: Please use the HTML code I posted below to measure the usable area on your device. Tested on almost every type of device ;-)

Comment: I used the iOS Simulator running iOS 7.1 (11D167) and found that the chrome of Safari is now 97px in height rather than 96px. Thus, landscape is 1024x671 and portrait is 768x927. [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012135/ios-7-ipad-safari-landscape-innerheight-outerheight-layout-issue#comment32062380_20007084) supports my findings.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know screen aspects you could check [iPad Peek](http://ipadpeek.com) and load a site like [NYTIMES](http://nytimes.com). this gives the exact usable screen dimensions for the iPad.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

So - on my ipad (ipad1, ios 5.1.1) I got slightly different numbers than above. Probably because the tab and bookmarks bars are showing. 
My values:

```
    portrait  : 768  x 900
    landscape : 1024 x 644
```

So I wrote a javascript bookmarklet to get a proof positive result. You can email this to yourself, goto "about:blank" in safari, create a bookmark, edit it and cut/paste this code out of email :)

When you get the bookmarklet running re-size the div until it matches the window and tada..

```
<pre><code>
javascript:( function(){
  "use strict";
  var bmIdVal = "ios_screen_res_test_bookmarklet";
  var bmDivSize = {
    w : 320,
    h : 240 
  };

  var vpMeta1 = document.createElement('meta');
  vpMeta1.setAttribute("name","viewport");
  vpMeta1.setAttribute("content",'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
  document.head.appendChild(vpMeta1);

  function updateStatus(){
    statusDiv.innerHTML = "div is " + bmDivSize.w + ',' + bmDivSize.h + 
      " doc body says: " + document.body.clientWidth + "," + 
      document.body.clientHeight;
  }

  function resizeBmDiv(wPx,hPx){
    bmDivSize.w += wPx;
    bmDivSize.h += hPx;
    bmDiv.style.width=bmDivSize.w + "px";
    bmDiv.style.height=bmDivSize.h + "px";
    updateStatus();
  }

  var prevBmDiv = document.getElementById(bmIdVal); 
  if( prevBmDiv != null){
    document.body.removeChild(prevBmDiv);
  }
  var bmDiv = document.createElement("div");
  bmDiv.setAttribute("id",bmIdVal);
  bmDiv.style.cssText = 
    "position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;background-color: #0066FF";
  bmDiv.style.width=bmDivSize.w + "px";
  bmDiv.style.height=bmDivSize.h + "px";

  var sizerB_w1 = document.createElement("button");
  sizerB_w1.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
  sizerB_w1.innerHTML="w+1";
  sizerB_w1.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(1,0);
  };
  var sizerB_w100 = document.createElement("button");
  sizerB_w100.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
  sizerB_w100.innerHTML="w+100";
  sizerB_w100.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(100,0);
  };
  var sizerB_h1 = document.createElement("button");
  sizerB_h1.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
  sizerB_h1.innerHTML="h+1";
  sizerB_h1.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(0,1);
  };
  var sizerB_h100 = document.createElement("button");
  sizerB_h100.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
  sizerB_h100.innerHTML="h+100";
  sizerB_h100.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(0,100);
  };

  var sizerDiv = document.createElement('div');
  sizerDiv.appendChild(sizerB_w1);
  sizerDiv.appendChild(sizerB_w100);
  sizerDiv.appendChild(sizerB_h1);
  sizerDiv.appendChild(sizerB_h100);

  var sizerB_wm1 = document.createElement("button");
  sizerB_wm1.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
  sizerB_wm1.innerHTML="w-1";
  sizerB_wm1.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(-1,0);
  };
  var sizerB_wm100 = document.createElement("button");
  sizerB_wm100.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
  sizerB_wm100.innerHTML="w-100";
  sizerB_wm100.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(-100,0);
  };
  var sizerB_hm1 = document.createElement("button");
  sizerB_hm1.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
  sizerB_hm1.innerHTML="h-1";
  sizerB_hm1.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(0,-1);
  };
  var sizerB_hm100 = document.createElement("button");
  sizerB_hm100.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
  sizerB_hm100.innerHTML="h-100";
  sizerB_hm100.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(0,-100);
  };

  var sizerMDiv = document.createElement('div');
  sizerMDiv.appendChild(sizerB_wm1);
  sizerMDiv.appendChild(sizerB_wm100);
  sizerMDiv.appendChild(sizerB_hm1);
  sizerMDiv.appendChild(sizerB_hm100);

  var statusDiv = document.createElement('div');
  statusDiv.style.cssText = "color:white;";

  bmDiv.appendChild(statusDiv);
  bmDiv.appendChild(sizerDiv);
  bmDiv.appendChild(sizerMDiv);
  document.body.appendChild(bmDiv);
  updateStatus();  
})();
</code></pre>
```

Comment: What an awesome idea!!! I generated an HTML file with that JS code and it works so great on any device! Just replace:
'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'
with
'initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' for correct scaling on iPad when you rotate the device (a reload is still necessary).

Comment: EDIT: I attach my entire HTML file, with buttons w+10 and h+10 added, reload forced and viewport corrected below! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I have not yet started coding for iPad but got these by googling. Might prove useful
https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/04/06/ipad-web-development-tips/
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

I have edited Andy Idsinga answer, creating an HTML document you can upload anywhere and run on your devices. I've corrected viewport metatag and set automatic reload on screen rotation. I've also added w+10, w-10, h+10, h-10 buttons. Please upvote also Andy if you like this, since he was the original author!

```
<html><head>
<title>Screen resolution test (usable area)</title>
</head><body>
<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";
var bmIdVal = "ios_screen_res_test_bookmarklet";
var bmDivSize = {
    w : 320,
    h : 240 
};

var vpMeta1 = document.createElement('meta');
vpMeta1.setAttribute("name","viewport");
vpMeta1.setAttribute("content",'initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0');
document.head.appendChild(vpMeta1);

function updateStatus(){
statusDiv.innerHTML = "div is " + bmDivSize.w + ',' + bmDivSize.h + 
    " doc body says: " + document.body.clientWidth + "," + 
    document.body.clientHeight;
}

function resizeBmDiv(wPx,hPx){
    bmDivSize.w += wPx;
    bmDivSize.h += hPx;
    bmDiv.style.width=bmDivSize.w + "px";
    bmDiv.style.height=bmDivSize.h + "px";
    updateStatus();
}

var prevBmDiv = document.getElementById(bmIdVal); 
if( prevBmDiv != null){
    document.body.removeChild(prevBmDiv);
}
var bmDiv = document.createElement("div");
bmDiv.setAttribute("id",bmIdVal);
bmDiv.style.cssText = "position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;background-color: #0066FF";
bmDiv.style.width=bmDivSize.w + "px";
bmDiv.style.height=bmDivSize.h + "px";

var sizerB_w1 = document.createElement("button");
sizerB_w1.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
sizerB_w1.innerHTML="w+1";
sizerB_w1.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(1,0);
};
var sizerB_w100 = document.createElement("button");
sizerB_w100.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
sizerB_w100.innerHTML="w+100";
sizerB_w100.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(100,0);
};
var sizerB_h1 = document.createElement("button");
sizerB_h1.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
sizerB_h1.innerHTML="h+1";
sizerB_h1.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(0,1);
};
var sizerB_h100 = document.createElement("button");
sizerB_h100.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
sizerB_h100.innerHTML="h+100";
sizerB_h100.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(0,100);
};

var sizerDiv = document.createElement('div');
sizerDiv.appendChild(sizerB_w1);
sizerDiv.appendChild(sizerB_w100);
sizerDiv.appendChild(sizerB_h1);
sizerDiv.appendChild(sizerB_h100);

var sizerB_wm1 = document.createElement("button");
sizerB_wm1.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
sizerB_wm1.innerHTML="w-1";
sizerB_wm1.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(-1,0);
};
var sizerB_wm100 = document.createElement("button");
sizerB_wm100.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
sizerB_wm100.innerHTML="w-100";
sizerB_wm100.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(-100,0);
};
var sizerB_hm1 = document.createElement("button");
sizerB_hm1.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
sizerB_hm1.innerHTML="h-1";
sizerB_hm1.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(0,-1);
};
var sizerB_hm100 = document.createElement("button");
sizerB_hm100.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
sizerB_hm100.innerHTML="h-100";
sizerB_hm100.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(0,-100);
};

var sizerMDiv = document.createElement('div');
sizerMDiv.appendChild(sizerB_wm1);
sizerMDiv.appendChild(sizerB_wm100);
sizerMDiv.appendChild(sizerB_hm1);
sizerMDiv.appendChild(sizerB_hm100);

var sizerC_w10 = document.createElement("button");
sizerC_w10.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
sizerC_w10.innerHTML="w+10";
sizerC_w10.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(10,0);
};
var sizerC_h10 = document.createElement("button");
sizerC_h10.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
sizerC_h10.innerHTML="h+10";
sizerC_h10.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(0,10);
};
var sizerC_Mw10 = document.createElement("button");
sizerC_Mw10.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
sizerC_Mw10.innerHTML="w-10";
sizerC_Mw10.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(-10,0);
};
var sizerC_Mh10 = document.createElement("button");
sizerC_Mh10.style.cssText = "width:64px;height:64px";
sizerC_Mh10.innerHTML="h-10";
sizerC_Mh10.onclick = function(evt){
    resizeBmDiv(0,-10);
};

var sizerCDiv = document.createElement('div');
sizerCDiv.appendChild(sizerC_w10);
sizerCDiv.appendChild(sizerC_h10);
sizerCDiv.appendChild(sizerC_Mw10);
sizerCDiv.appendChild(sizerC_Mh10);

var statusDiv = document.createElement('div');
statusDiv.style.cssText = "color:white;";

bmDiv.appendChild(statusDiv);
bmDiv.appendChild(sizerDiv);
bmDiv.appendChild(sizerMDiv);
bmDiv.appendChild(sizerCDiv);
document.body.appendChild(bmDiv);
updateStatus();

window.onresize = function(event) {
    document.location.reload(true);
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are wrong. 
The actual size of header of ipad is 64px.
Therefore, in portrait orientation of ipad is =  768X960 and landscape orientation is = 1024x704
You can also check the total dimension of ipad in portrait and landscape orientations including header height as 64px then it will show portrait and landscape orientation as 768x1024

Comment: Do you have anything to back that up?

Answer (score 0):

The above "correct" answer is actually wrong as it doesn't take into account the black status bar at the top of the ipad screen showing the time, battery life etc. This is an extra 18px of screen that is taken up.

So the usable screen area in Safari is actually: 
landscape: 1024x672 
portrait: 768x928

Comment: I'm not at a computer to chech this, but I believe you can set the status bar as transparent and then retain that space.

Answer (score 0):

Just check http://benfrain.com/downloads/respond.html to view the current dimensions of the viewport.

Or even nicer use this bookmarklet:
http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/
This will show current dimensions for all sort of devices (can also be customized). Can be tested with every website.