# iPad web viewport size

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad

I'm working on a specific web layout for multiple devices and browsers (desktop and mobile).  I want the web app to be full-screen all the time, with no scrolling in either direction.

I'm using JavaScript to read the available height and width of the screen `(document.documentElement.clientWidth, clientHeight)`, then setting my elements to fit.  In my simple test case, I've got an absolute positioned div tag `(top:0; left:0;)` with width and height set (via JavaScript) to 4 pixels less than the screen width and height, with a 2px wide border on all 4 sides.

On desktop browsers and Chrome on a couple of Android devices it works as intended - I see the border at the edges all the way around and no scrolling.

On an iPad 2 and an iPad Mini (Safari), however, the resulting div is the correct width but 20 pixels too tall - I've got to scroll a bit to see the bottom border.

I get the same results when I do it with just CSS, using:

```
  #borderDiv {
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    border:2px solid black;
  }
```

I'm using: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Why am I getting a "wrong" height result on iPad devices?

David

Comment: what do you have as metatags

Comment: Aha, found another post with same issue.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012135/ios-7-ipad-safari-landscape-innerheight-outerheight-layout-issue

Comment: meta tags: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">