# Why does the iOS Safari user agent stylesheet appear to override my margin style on the body?

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, margin

Why does the following markup result in `body` having an 8px `margin` on iOS (latest iPad) (and hence a vertical scrollbar)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px !important;">
  </body>
</html>
```

Online here: http://limitless-refuge-4707.herokuapp.com/index3

iOS 7.0.4

**Edit:**

Using the iPad web inspector I can see that the iOS Safari user-agent stylesheet style for a `margin-top: 8px` on the body is overriding my own styles. Why might this be?

Comment: add in css this: `* {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}`

Comment: the problem remains. Could I be missing an iOS metatag?

Comment: I've found a methode to scan your file: [wernull.com](http://wernull.com/2013/04/debug-ghost-css-elements-causing-unwanted-scrolling/)

Comment: I believe I can see what is causing the unwanted scrollbar - the user agent stylesheet applies an 8px margin-top despite my style on the body tag. I cannot understand why the user agent is overriding my style specification though...

Comment: Well, try this one out: [Width for Mobile Browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag), i really hope this block the problem you got.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: This does not appear to fix things. I am updating my version of iOS from 7.0.4. Interestingly, Chrome for iOS does not exhibit this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Safari on iPad with iOS7. It remains in 7.0.6.

[iOS 7 iPad Safari Landscape innerHeight/outerHeight layout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012135/ios-7-ipad-safari-landscape-innerheight-outerheight-layout-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the html element to have 100% height aswell

Comment: This has no effect unfortunately.