# javascript detect ios7 ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, detection

following the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012135/ios-7-ipad-safari-landscape-innerheight-outerheight-layout-issue), I'm trying to add a class to html for handling iPad landscape layout issues.

But the JS to detect iPad iOS7 doesn't seem to work anymore:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad;.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i)) {
$('html').addClass('ipad ios7');
}
```

I tried it on an iPad4 iOS7.

Can anyone confirm that the detection code is working for them?

EDIT: thanks to Waki's test page, we can be sure it is working.

And going through my 800 lines of app code again thoroughly, I found that I called my function that includes the code for the check from within document.ready but the function itself was placed outside of document.ready and therefore was not called. Really stupid mistake. I apologize to all who wasted their time on reading this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

are included jQuery library for use $('html') ? Because this regex is working.

Comment: yes,jQuery is included and working. I call this code in $(document).ready function

Comment: http://coding.kz/stack/ios.html Here i prepared test page, with this regex, check it.

Comment: thank you for that. I'll have to check why it is not working for me.

Comment: sorry, can't vote you up here. not enough reputation :-(