# Prevent Chrome Browser Address Bar from Auto-Hiding in iOS Devices

Tags: javascript, ios, css, google-chrome, address-bar

I'm looking for a solution that prevents the Chrome Address Bar from hiding on an iPhone/iPad, when scrolling down. MailChimp has gotten this to work. If you're logged in to MailChimp and using an iPhone/iPad you'll notice the Chrome Address Bar is locked at the top. The elastic scrolling is still in place, but that Address Bar is locked in place. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set your body element's height to be correct size. For web apps without the  address bar I think it's supposed to be `height: 672px !important;`  See this question:

[iOS 7 iPad Safari Landscape innerHeight/outerHeight layout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012135/ios-7-ipad-safari-landscape-innerheight-outerheight-layout-issue)

Comment: Thanks Bjorn Tipling. While that does prevent auto-hiding, I can no longer scroll down if the page is below the fold, even with overflow-y:scroll. I like this solution, but it's not quite there.

Comment: Make a container div with y-axis scrolling that envelopes the rest of your content.

Comment: I added scroll to an envelope div, which does give me the ability to scroll on y-axis, but because it's a div scroll versus the browser scroll, it's not quite as smooth when compared to the MailChimp solution. This approach also loses the elastic scrolling effect. So far the best solution though;

Comment: Have you tried looking at MailChimp's css? Also try setting the css on HTML instead of body. I'd have to experiment at this point.